# How to use unity-2d-panel standalone with global menu

Tags: unity-2d

Can anyone tell me how to use only unity-2d-panel with global menu. When I load only unity-2d-panel I have problems with global menu, for example: I have close, minimize and maximize buttons on unity panel and on window title bar. I think it's a bug. So can you help me fixing it.

Comment: I'm actually able to run unity-2d-panel just fine without unity-2d-shell or any other unity processes running. For me, the global menu works as expected, so I think you're running into some kind of bug, or perhaps you have another process running somewhere that's interfering with the global menu. For reference, I'm running compiz, unity-2d-panel, glx-dock, and nautilus together as the Desktop Environment on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Don't know, this also happends in Ubuntu 12.10. I tried using cairo dock session but I got same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is somewhat vague in areas, so I will answer it the best I can given my understanding of what you are asking.

You can run the unity-2d panel with the dash from another DE (like Lubuntu) after installing `unity-2d` (and all the things it pulls in) by pressing Alt+F2 and typing in `unity-2d-shell`  (or opening a terminal and using the same command)
This will give you the lefthand sidebar with the dash. However, this will interfere with your Lubuntu setup as Nautilus handles the desktop, etc...

If however you are just trying to run unity-2d log out and choose it from your session menu.

`unity-2d-panel` is the upper panel with global menu integration.

unity is a very self integrated DE, and it is not good at playing with other DE (like LXDE, XFCE4...)  So problems can easily occur trying to use the panel only, or the sidebar only in another DE.

**edit:** since my post was down-voted with no reason given, I will add more information here. Though the lack of clarity in the question requires somewhat ambiguous answers, I will continue to try to address my understanding of what the OP *might* want to do.

Running unity-2d-panel global menu by itself is pointless.  A window manager is needed.  if you are trying to remove the `unity-2d-shell` from your current session, edit your `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu-2d.session` file removing the `DefaultProvider-shell=unity-2d-shell` line and the word `shell`; from the `RequiredProviders` line.

If you are trying to run it from another window manager then running it with `unity-2d-panel` **may** work but by *only* using some of the components of Unity (a very tightly integrated DE) will probably cause you issues.  unity-2d has been abandoned in all future releases of Ubuntu, so this is only pertains to the LTS (and the older releases that are soon to lose support like 11.10 at the current time of writing this)

P.S. launchpad is the place to report bugs, if you believe this is a bug file it there.